# Ruby: reduce duplication while initialize hash

Tags: ruby

```
array = [0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6]

hash = {
   "key1" => array[0..2],
   "key2" => array[0..3],
   "key3" => array,
   "key4" => array,
   "key5" => array,
   "key6" => array,   
   "key7" => array
}
```

Is there a way I can remove the duplication by doing something like

```
hash = {
   "key1" => array[0..2],
   "key2" => array[0..3],
    %(key3, key4, key5, key6, key7).each {|ele| ele => array}
}
```

Comment: I think your first way is more readable than any of the alternatives. Note also that if you ever plan to modify key3-7, you probably want `=> array.dup` instead of `=> array`, as the latter will assign 5 references to the same array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array = [0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6]
h = Hash[*Array.new(7) {|x| ["key#{x+1}", array[0..(x<2?x+2:-1)]]}.flatten(1)]
h # => {"key1" => [0, 0.3, 0.4], "key2" => [0.3, 0.4, 0.2],...}
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be readable? Regardless, that's very nice.

Comment: Would be interesting to see what the valid result is supposed to be if/when another element is added to array.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
array = [0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6]
hash = {
   "key1" => array[0..2],
   "key2" => array[0..3]
}
%w(key3 key4 key5 key6 key7).each {|ele| hash[ele] = array}
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, but you need to remove the commas from your string array.

Comment: @Phrogz did a copy/paste from original. Fixed in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: No, you haven't yet. You still have `%w(key3 key4, key5, key6, key7)` which creates the strings named `"key4,"`, `"key5,"`, and `"key6,"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple variations on a theme. They work with 1.8.7 or 1.9.2. The insertion order is maintained with 1.9.2 'cause that's what it does:

```
require 'pp'

array = [0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6]

hash = ('key3'..'key7').entries.inject({}) { |m, e| m[e] = array; m }
hash.merge!('key1' => array[0..2], 'key2' => array[0..3])
pp hash 

puts '-' * 40

hash = {
  'key1' => array[0..2], 
  'key2' => array[0..3]
  }.merge(('key3'..'key7').entries.inject({}) { |m, e| m[e] = array; m })
pp hash

puts '-' * 40

# I think this is the most readable/maintainable
hash = {
  'key1' => array[0..2], 
  'key2' => array[0..3]
}
('key3'..'key7').entries.inject(hash) { |m, e| m[e] = array; m }
pp hash
```

Which output:

```
# >> {"key3"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
# >>  "key4"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
# >>  "key5"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
# >>  "key6"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
# >>  "key7"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
# >>  "key1"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4],
# >>  "key2"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2]}
# >> ----------------------------------------
# >> {"key1"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4],
# >>  "key2"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2],
# >>  "key3"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
# >>  "key4"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
# >>  "key5"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
# >>  "key6"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
# >>  "key7"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6]}
# >> ----------------------------------------
# >> {"key1"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4],
# >>  "key2"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2],
# >>  "key3"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
# >>  "key4"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
# >>  "key5"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
# >>  "key6"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
# >>  "key7"=>[0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version:

```
hash = {
   "key1" => array[0..2],
   "key2" => array[0..3]
}.tap { |h| ("key3".."key7").each{|k| h[k]=array}}
```